# connectServiceAction in HWIOAuthBundle. It ask connect even if user is already connect

Tags: symfony, oauth, fosuserbundle, facebook-oauth, hwioauthbundle

I'm using HWIOAuthBundle with Symfony 2.4.4.

I implemented the Facebook login: if you point your browser to /login/facebook it asks you to authenticate and it works flawlessly.

Unfortunately if you try to visit again this page while you are still logged in it will ask you to connect your account with Facebook (!?) which makes no sense!

Asking to connect the account with Facebook makes sense only if you are logged in with an internally created account (for example an account created with FOS User Bundle), but it makes no sense trying to connect a Facebook account with the same Facebook account!

Comment: are you using Login VIA Firewalls or some manual sessions handling ?

Comment: I'm using Login VIA Firewalls

Comment: do you actually see the OauthToken in your web profiler ?